# Updating Recoil State without Triggering Re-Render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, recoiljs

I'm using Recoil to keep track of the last selected accordion the user has open. The amount of accordions that are rendered on the page can vary between 10 to 250 accordions based on a workflow that is dynamically generated.

I wanted to know if anyone knew how to update a Recoil atom without triggering a re-render. If I have the Recoil state updating using a useRecoilCallback, on a good strong device it still takes ~1 second or more for it to register my click and change with the rendering. If I remove the Recoil state on being set, it renders and registers the clicks immediately.

I want to know if there would be a way to update the SelectedCategories atom without causing a render. Each one of these accordions has 15+ additional accordion components and when I toggle one, every single Accordion and it's children accordions re-render.

```
const SelectedCategories = useRecoilCallback(({ snapshot }) => () => snapshot.getLoadable(_SelectedCategories).contents, [Inspection.id]);
const setSelectedCategories = useRecoilCallback(({ set }) => (n) => {
    set(_SelectedCategories, n);
  }, []);
```

```js
const openAccordion = () => {
  let usc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SelectedCategories()));
  usc.category = usc.category === propKey ? '' : propKey;
  setSelectedCategories(usc);
}
```

```
<Accordion defaultExpanded={SelectedCategories.contents?.category === propKey || false} id={propKey}>
  <AccordionSummary onClick={openAccordion}>
  { /* Accordion Summary Header */ }
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
  { /* Accordion Details Here */ }    
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an [atomFamily](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/utils/atomFamily) for `SelectedCategories` instead? That way you would have a single atom for each accordion, instead of 1 atom for all.